# CFFile is turning my CSS file into gibberish

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working on a widget with some backend settings. One of the settings would allow clients to provide their own CSS files to customize the look of the widget. I put a link to a base CSS file, they download it, make their changes and reupload it to create their own custom theme.

The problem is when I try to upload the file, it uploads but turns it into gibberish. Example:

–wTSÙ‡Ï½7½Ð" %ôz  Ò;HQ‰I€P†„&vDF)VdTÀG‡"cEƒ‚b×  òPÆÁQDEåÝŒk    ï­5óÞšýÇYßÙç·×Ùgï}×º�Pü‚ÂtX€4¡XîëÁ\     ËÄ÷XÀáffGøDÔü½=™™¨HÆ³öî.€d»Û,¿P&sÖÿ‘"7C$�EÕ6<~&å”S³Å2ÿÊô•)2†12¡ ¢¬"ãÄ¯lö§æ+»É˜—&ä¡YÎ¼4žŒ»PÞš%á£Œ¡\˜%àg£|e½TIš�å÷(ÓÓøœL�0™_Ìç&¡l‰2Eî‰ò�”Ä9¼r‹ù9hž�x¦gäŠ‰Ib¦×˜iåèÈfúñ³Sùb1+”ÃMáˆxLÏô´Ž0€¯o–E%Ym™h‘í­

Here is my upload code:

```
<cffile 
    action="UPLOAD" 
    filefield="form.vchrThemeFile"
    destination="C:\path\to\directory\"
    accept="text/css"
    nameconflict="makeunique">
```

I am using enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form.

```
<form action="<cfoutput>#submit#</cfoutput>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to give us a complete repro case, not just a coupla disassociated lines of code. This is not normal behaviour, so it's something to do with your code. As to what it is, we cannot comment, without seeing example code that demonstrates the problem. Include a sample CSS file as well.(http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Also what flavor and version of CF are you using? Can you drop in a cfdump and give us a screenshot or paste of that. I found two other people on the same page having a similar problem and one traced it to his "firefox corrupting files". It's not likely but have you tried using other computers/browsers?

Comment: First guess would be some kind of compression technique that is being used somewhere in your code. The cdfump requested by cfqueryparam would be very helpful to help identify the issue.

Comment: Its really weird. The problem went away on its own. I worked on it sunday and it was returning gibberish and Monday it started working... Maybe it was a server bug. I don't know. I'll keep an eye on it.